# Compiling programs with packages in java using windows command line

Tags: java, compilation

I have a .java file which i compiled in a package named "Mypack",using command line as follows

```
javac -d . file_name.java     // The "." specifies the current working directory which was the desktop
```

so it creates a folder on the desktop named "Mypack"(The package name), in the folder the .class file for my program is placed.Now i did the following

```
java -classpath "C:\Users\LoRd CuRZon\Desktop\Mypack" file_name     //  Error Could not find or load main method
```

Even if i go into the directory "Mypack" and launch  command prompt from that directory and  try to run the program i still get the same error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: have you added any package statement into source file , then please provide me.

Comment: is it a simple java file or it contains main method?

Comment: This works but i still don't understand why cant i just go to the directory of the file and write     java   file_name  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run it as likewise from Desktop,

```
c:/.../Desktop> java Mypack.file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

`java`  command requires fully qualified name .

so from desktop run `java Mypack.classname`

Answer (score 1):

If you  have this error:

```
 Error Could not find or load main method
```

That means you don't write a main method in you code try to write it.
But befor to do those steps:
Fo compiling a programme do this:

```
java Mypack.file_name
```

To run it do like this:

```
java Mypack.classname
```